# Excel formula for counting row number starting below

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that would find and count the row number from below the cell. This may have duplicates however, I only want to count the first data found starting below. In this case 9 is 6 cell away from **F7**. There's also a 9 value from cell **D1** but since 9 in **F2** is the first data found starting bellow it should return as 6. This is really giving me a headache. I need help. The formula should start at cell **I2** to **I11**

**Example**:
[image]

Comment: You're gonna need to explain in more detail what you want as it is not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: agreed, I do not know how you are counting your gaps  or what gaps is referring to.  As such I cant figure out how 6 works into the answer.

Comment: @Graham im sorry. sir i wanted a formula that would count the row number of the data starting bellow. example is 9 and it is 6 counts from bellow.

Comment: I think wat you want is to set the row without data as the lower limit. Next you check for each defined name on what row it is found (starting from the bottom) so that every lowest occurence of the name is returned. Then substract this row number from the lower limit. That's how you get your values on the right. Am I correct?

Comment: @Wouter yeah but the thing is i don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=MAX(ROW(A$1:F$7))-LARGE(IF(A$1:F$7=H2,ROW(A$1:F$7)),1)+1
```

When you entered the formula you have to press CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER. So not just ENTER. 
Enter this formula in I2 and then fill down.
It looks for last row on which the desired value is found. And then substracts it from the row of the last found data (+1).

Comment: thanks man! too bad it has to be an array formula thought. It would have been great if it wasn't an array formula. ill check this as the answer anyways.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

nothing better, but doing this comes to mind:

```
=counta($A$1:$A$7)-
 min(
  iferror(match(H2,$A$1:$A$7,0),99999),
  iferror(match(H2,$B$1:$B$7,0),99999),
  iferror(match(H2,$C$1:$C$7,0),99999),
  ...
  iferror(match(H2,$F$1:$F$7,0),99999)
 )
+1
```

Comment: your formula looks very promising and plain dude and its not an array formula really great i like it but doesn't seems to work with the other values.